# Olimexino 328 upload problem

Tags: arduino

I'm young user of Arduino IDE and with my new Olimexino-328 it's quite impossible to upload any sketch without stk500 sync error :

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "D:\Ard_Oli_Dev\arduino-1.04\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM2
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: 
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

I don't know what version of optiboot is installed. 
If someone as an idea, I'll appreciate  Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified serial communciation/port setup?  Does your board have RX/TX led's?  If so, if you open the serial port monitor tool can you get them to flash by typing in a line of random text and sending it to the board?  Do you know that you have chosen the right board configuration (settings such as baud) for the bootloader in your board?

Comment: What is the command you execute? And what is the contents of `D:\Ard_Oli_Dev\arduino-1.04\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf`

Answer (score 2):

It is odd that they are using 57600 baud since it has a 16MHz crystal.  Have you tried treating the board as a uno and uploading at 115200?

Also note the two FAQs at the bottom of their web site, the second seems especially relevant. From https://www.olimex.com/Products/Duino/AVR/OLIMEXINO-328/open-source-hardware

```
I can't upload my code via Arduino IDE. Where is the problem?
The board is recognized as Arduino DueMilanove /w ATmega328 in Arduino IDE.

Make sure you have selected exactly that. Also check which port the board uses
and adjust it in Tools->Serial.

I do everything as supposed but when I try to upload code via the USB I receive the
following error: "avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00". What is wrong?

It is very likely that your OLIMEXINO-328 would work as expected if you install FTDI
drivers that are NOT newer than 2.08.14. There is good chance you are using the latest
FTDI at the moment. The whole problem is explained in details in this forum post: FTDI
bug in FT232R with week code 1213
```